# Gestionar Ubicacion de una nueva ventana

Tags: php, bootstrap

espero me puedan ayudar, o por lo menos orientar, estoy haciendo una pagina de prueba (solo para aprendizaje), en cual tengo 2 nav-bar de Bootstrap, una superior y una vertical, en la barra vertical tengo un par opciones que llamaran a otras paginas (links), sera pocible abrir las paginas nuevas en el area que que esta en blanco. (Adjunto imagen).

Con este codigo estan inlcuidas las opciones del menu vertical.

```
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-lnk pl-0" href="#"><i class="fas fa-table fa-fw"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Tabla</span></a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fas fa-images fa-fw"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Imagenes</span></a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart codeply fa-fw"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Codeply</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fas fa-star codeply fa-fw"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Link</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fas fa-star fa-fw"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Link</span></a>
            </li>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí, claro que es posible, pero hay varias formas de hacerlo. Has intentado algo o buscas un modo en particular?

Comment: He buscado pero no encotre algo exacto.. ya que no se que ando buscando, en este minuto cualquier idea me sirve, algo no muy rebuscado dado mi como conocimiento del lenguaje, hasta el nombre del procedieminto o funcion me sirve, asi puedo acotar la busqueda.

Comment: [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/305310/edit) y añade el código completo que tienes para así poder ofrecerte una posible solución.